# Check if PySaprk column values exists in another dataframe column values

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to figure out the condition to check if the values of one PySpark dataframe exist in another PySpark dataframe, and if so extract the value and compare again. I was thinking of doing a multiple `withColumn()` with a `when()` function.

For example my two dataframes can be something like:

```
df1
| id    | value |
| ----- | ----  |
| hello | 1111  |
| world | 2222  |

df2
| id     | value |
| ------ | ----  |
| hello  | 1111  |
| world  | 3333  |
| people | 2222  |
```

And the result I wish to obtain is to check first if the value of `df1.id` exists in `df2.id` and if true return me the `df2.value`, for example I was trying something like:

```
df1 = df1.withColumn("df2_value", when(df1.id == df2.id, df2.value))
```

So I get something like:

```
df1
| id    | value | df2_value |
| ----- | ----  | --------- |
| hello | 1111  | 1111      |
| world | 2222  | 3333      |
```

So that now I can do another check between these two value columns in the `df1` dataframe, and return a boolean column (`1`or `0`) in a new dataframe.

The result I wish to get would be something like:

```
df3
| id    | value | df2_value | match |
| ----- | ----  | --------- | ----- |
| hello | 1111  | 1111      | 1     |
| world | 2222  | 3333      | 0     |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Left join `df1` with `df2` on `id` after prefixing all df2 columns except `id` with `df2_*`:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1 = spark.createDataFrame([("hello", 1111), ("world", 2222)], ["id", "value"])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([("hello", 1111), ("world", 3333), ("people", 2222)], ["id", "value"])

df = df1.join(
    df2.select("id", *[F.col(c).alias(f"df2_{c}") for c in df2.columns if c != 'id']),
    ["id"],
    "left"
)
```

Then using `functools.reduce` you can construct a boolean expression to check if columns match in the 2 dataframes like this:

```
from functools import reduce

check_expr = reduce(
    lambda acc, x: acc & (F.col(x) == F.col(f"df2_{x}")),
    [c for c in df1.columns if c != 'id'],
    F.lit(True)
)
    
df.withColumn("match", check_expr.cast("int")).show()
#+-----+-----+---------+-----+
#|   id|value|df2_value|match|
#+-----+-----+---------+-----+
#|hello| 1111|     1111|    1|
#|world| 2222|     3333|    0|
#+-----+-----+---------+-----+
```